# What is the difference between 日曜日【にちようび】and 日曜【にちよう】?

Tags: word-choice, abbreviations

In all the japanese learning books, they teach you that xxxday ends with 曜日.

But sometimes I get to see xxx曜 only without the "Day" Kanji.

Can I shorten it when speaking too or is it only written ? And when can I shorten it ?

Comment: I think we say 日曜参観, (運転免許の)日曜更新, 日曜新聞, (理容室の)月曜固定祝日, (教会の)日曜学校, etc., not 日曜日参観, 日曜日新聞...　so maybe "~曜" is more used to make compound words.

Comment: I just noticed that young children say 「~~曜日」, not 「~~曜」. I think ~~曜日 sounds a bit more casual than 曜, though I read some people say "曜日 is politer than 曜" in some webpages.

Comment: Interesting fact ! Thank you for the comment :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not clear cut, but my impression is that the tendency is that 日曜日 means a particular day that is Sunday whereas 日曜 means Sunday in general or series of Sundays.

> 日曜日に出掛けます。
>   'I will go out on next Sunday.'
>
> 日曜に出掛けます。
>   'I go out on Sundays.'

When it is clear that it is not about a particular day but is about a series of days, this contrast becomes clear.

> * 日曜日洋画劇場
>
> 日曜洋画劇場

Comment: I do not think that I personally make this distinction at all.  For me, both 日曜日に出掛けます and 日曜に出掛けます can refer to both an activity on a particular Sunday and about a regular activity on Sundays.  I do not rule out the possibility that I am making the stated distinction without being aware of it myself, but at least this explanation does not hit me as convincing.

Comment: I think both can be interpreted as the same meaning. We can't determine which means which by reading just individual sentences without their contexts. If there were a tiny tendency actually, we should not depend upon it to avoid miscommunication.

Comment: This is incorrect. They have the same meaning, and the final 日 was added in the Meiji period to make spoken language easier. You may hear these examples simply because you don't say 日曜 out loud as much.

Answer (score 1):

When you say

> But sometimes I get to see xxx曜 only without the "Day" Kanji.

do you mean in your books?  Or other places too?

I personally only use it in informal situations like speaking with/emailing friends.  I can't say I've ever seen it written this way non-informally.

Comment: I saw the "short" form on Facebook and other similar websites not in books yet.