# Is there a reason for the days of the week being written and pronounced without the 日?

Tags: word-choice

I sometimes see the days of the week written without 日. Are there specific reasons on when 日would not be used?

Comment: Related (or duplicate?): http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26004/9831

Comment: @shoko I have accepted the comment from broken headphones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a informal way of saying.

For example:

> 月曜にまた会おう

This sentence gives listeners a friendly-impression. So you can't say 月曜, 火曜, 水曜, … to your boss.